# Grunt trying to install grunt-contrib-concat package with a warning

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, installation

I am trying to run grunt for my angular project. I run below command.

```
npm install grunt-contrib-concat
```

And it gives me below warning in command line.

```
WARN package.json grunt-cli@0.1.13 No license field.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always expected to mention about the licence in the package.json so-that other people will get to know whether they have permission to use the project or not.  So, if you mention about this licence in the package.json, you will not get that warning.

To know more https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#license